# Terraform aws provider plugin download issue in version 0.10.3

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

we are using the terraform v0.10.3, it's a little bit old version, agreed with that point. Two days back, I can able to run the terraform commands with that version successfully.

While checking today it is failing with the below error. Is there any changes happened from terraform side? Any one encountering same issue?

```
Error installing provider "aws": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity.
Terraform analyses the configuration and state and automatically downloads
plugins for the providers used. However, when attempting to download this
plugin an unexpected error occured.
```

With the aws terraform provider version "0.11.13", getting below warning message.

```
Warning: registry.terraform.io: This version of Terraform has an outdated GPG key and is unable to verify new provider releases. Please upgrade Terraform to at least 0.12.31 to receive new provider updates. For details see: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/hcsec-2021-12-codecov-security-event-and-hashicorp-gpg-key-exposure/23512



Warning: registry.terraform.io: This version of Terraform has an outdated GPG key and is unable to verify new provider releases. Please upgrade Terraform to at least 0.12.31 to receive new provider updates. For details see: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/hcsec-2021-12-codecov-security-event-and-hashicorp-gpg-key-exposure/23512
```

Any changes at the terraform backend components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this answer from terraform forums.
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-updates-for-hcsec-2021-12/23570